# Add Reports to Confluence

Tags: confluence

I am creating a Confluence page and I want to see if this is possible. I am using the Confluence Publisher Plugin for Jenkins to send a Results.html report to my space. This works great! Currently this appears as an attachment though on the page. I would rather that when you look at the page, you see the actual report vs clicking multiple links and end up downloading the file.

Is there a simple way to display *.html reports on a Confluence Page?

Answer (score 0):

After researching this some more is looks like it requires the Confluence HTML Plugin. Using Confluence is kind of like driving in New Jersey. No matter which direction you go in, you are going to hit a toll.